# How to add every four rows as column

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science, array-broadcasting

I have a very large numpy array like this. How can I convert this into

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

into this every two rows into one row? Although I need every four rows as one row?  This example would be helpful! I searched many places couldn't find a proper solution!

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

and then back again to

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.reshape()`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
...        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
...        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
...        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
...        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
...        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> b = a.reshape(3,16)
>>> b
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> b.reshape(6,8)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: what if the first array `a` has only five arrays? what can i do then..?

Comment: That would be an incomplete matrix. What do you expect the missing elements to be?